# Which python STL parts to include in Yocto-generated image?

Tags: python, yocto

I have a Python app using some 60 external packages.

I’ve used pipoe to create recipes for them and now they are neatly installed.

How do I find out which parts of the standard Python library to include in my image?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to inspect your app's Python imports, and note down any non-external and non-app imports (e.g. `import logging` or `import json`).

Some tools that might help with this are:

- [findimports](https://github.com/mgedmin/findimports)
- [pydeps](https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps)

Then, you can inspect Yocto's [`python3-manifest.json`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3/python3-manifest.json) file, which describes how the Python stdlib `.py` and .`so` libraries get split into various Yocto packages.

Note: that the `python3-core` package contains a lot of the stdlib already.

Comment: Thanks, I will give these tools a try. Seems like an awful task to do manually.